# Correct way of accessing last item of a class member vector

Tags: c++, vector

I reached the last element of the vector of a class from within main() function. But I am not sure if it was the correct way to do this. Here is the code part:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class myClass
{
public:
    std::vector <wstring> Vec;
    std::vector <wstring> Vec2;
    std::vector <wstring> Vec3;
    // ...
    std::vector <wstring> Vec35;
    myClass();
};
myClass::myClass() : Vec{ L"Init" }, Vec2{ L"Init" }, Vec3{ L"Init" }, Vec35{ L"Init" } {}


void func(std::vector<wstring>& v)
{
    v.push_back(L"The Last Element");
}

int main()
{
    myClass mC;

    func(mC.Vec);

    wstring last = *(((std::vector <wstring>&) mC.Vec).rbegin());   // Is it the correct way to do this?

    std::wcout << L"Last element reached from inside of main() function is : " << last << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Last element reached from inside of main() function is : The Last Element
```

Comment: When you have sequentially numbered variables, that's usually a sign that you want an array. `Vec[35];` should make initialization a bit easier if nothing else.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for pointing out. They are not the actual names. Actual names are very different.

Comment: The cast `(std::vector <wstring>&)` is unnecessary and very dangerous. If you write e.g. accidentally `(std::vector <string>&)` instead, your program will compile without error but will have undefined behavior. Don't use casts when not required and if required use the appropriate specialized cast (e.g. `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`, etc.), not the C style cast. The C style cast will cast almost everything to everything without warning you if it causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Though it's a descriptive way of saying that.

Just

```
wstring last = *mC.Vec.rbegin();
```

should suffice. No need of explicit casting required.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is much better now!

Answer (score 4):

Using `rbegin` is indeed one way. The cast is however unnecessary.

But a more direct way is using [`back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back). Unlike `rbegin` which gives you an iterator that must be dereferenced, `back` gives you a reference to the last item.

```
wstring last = mC.Vec.back();
```

Either way you should first check that the vector is not [`empty`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/empty).

Comment: Thank you very much! It feels very safe now.